# ASP.NET: Print functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, printing

I've a big form with below mentioned fields/controls:

> 1. SharePoint Peoplepicker
> 2. SharePoint DateTime control
> 3. TextBox Single/Multiline
> 4. Dropdowns
> 5. GridViews

I'm looking for a solution to print this form. Output print should be clean to ensure everything looks like labels while printing. If I change CSS e.g. for textbox, there are limitations viz. not all data of textbox would be visible. Is there a way to achieve this without having to do following:

> 1. Have Labels and show them while printing for each control
> 2. Convert gridviews with itemtemplate and have labels in template while printing.

Another requirement is to ensure that form fits in A4 paper.

Comment: Why not convert to PDF and then allow the user to print it? Benefits: you can customize the PDF to fit in the A4 layout, have the required labels  instead of fields. etc. If you don't want PDF, you can also create labels and keep it hidden and display only during print (`css media @print`) while hiding the fields from printing, but you will have to update each label before sending the print command.

Comment: @Nimesh, Great. Can you elaborate or link to, on how in PDF fields would become labels?

Comment: Not actually labels, but just *text*, refer [this great article from mikesdotnetting.com](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/80/create-pdfs-in-asp-net-getting-started-with-itextsharp)

Comment: @Nimesh, thank you. I went through it. So, I will have to create the document dynamically as user click on print button?

Comment: Yes, you can dynamically generate fine looking PDFs with the your required paper size, logo, header+footer etc. as you like.

Comment: @Nimesh, Isn't it similar to putting labels? In PDF approach, I'll have to write everything twice again; one for form & 2nd to print control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar assignment & I completed using below approach:

1. Create a 'Print preview' button which on click opens a dialog
2. Once dialog opens, run JavaScript/jQuery to clone your container & convert controls into static values - Each controls' values would be in span or control itself; Everything else but the span containing the value can be removed
3. Extra controls like row numbers in grid, warning messages, buttons or similar can be removed
4. Remove extra padding, margins & font size can further be reduced to fit A4 e.g. 8pt
5. Finally provide a 'Print' button which takes parent container & prints- **You can use printThis.js for this**